# How to handle duplicated Item in custom Listview extends BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I created a custom adapter to make sectioned ListView but the Item appear to duplicate itself.

It would display as follow:

```
Title 1
1 Item 1
2 Item 2
3 Item 3
4 Item 4
5 Item 5
Title 2
6 Item 6
7 Item 7
8 Item 8
9 Item 9
10 Item 10
Title 3
11 Item 11
12 Item 12
13 Item 13
1 Item 1     //Should be 14 Item 14
15 Item 15
```

How do to solve this problem?

Using the adapter in MainActivity

```
    adapter.addSection("Title 1");
    adapter.addItem("1", "Item 1");
    adapter.addItem("2", "Item 2");
    adapter.addItem("3", "Item 3");
    adapter.addItem("4", "Item 4");
    adapter.addItem("5", "Item 5");

    adapter.addSection("Title 2");
    adapter.addItem("6", "Item 6");
    adapter.addItem("7", "Item 7");
    adapter.addItem("8", "Item 8");
    adapter.addItem("9", "Item 9");
    adapter.addItem("10", "Item 10");

    adapter.addSection("Title 3");
    adapter.addItem("11", "Item 11");
    adapter.addItem("12", "Item 12");
    adapter.addItem("13", "Item 13");
    adapter.addItem("14", "Item 14");
    adapter.addItem("15", "Item 15");
```

**item_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Item Text"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**section_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textSection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Section Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<ItemRow> itemRow = new ArrayList<ItemRow>();
private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();
private ItemRow ir;

public CustomAdapter(Context context){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void addItem(String no, String s){
    ir = new ItemRow();
    ir.setNumbering(no);
    ir.setDetail(s);

    itemRow.add(ir);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSection(String title){
    ir = new ItemRow();
    ir.setTitle(title);

    sectionHeader.add(itemRow.size());
    itemRow.add(ir);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemRow.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemRow.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    ViewHolder holder;

    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    ItemRow row = itemRow.get(position);

    if(convertView == null){
        switch(rowType){
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_text, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textNumber);
            holder.detail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textItem);


            holder.number.setText(row.getNumbering());
            holder.detail.setText(row.getDetail());

            view.setTag(holder);
            break;
        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_text, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textSection);

            holder.title.setText(row.getTitle());

            view.setTag(holder);
            break;
        }
    } else{
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    return view;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView title, number, detail;
}

}
```

**ANSWER**

So i did finally found the solution. setText should be after the if else in getView

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;// = new ViewHolder();;

    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    ItemRow row = itemRow.get(position);

    if(convertView == null){
        switch(rowType){
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_text, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textNumber);
            holder.detail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textItem);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            break;
        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_text, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSection);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            break;
        }
    } else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(rowType == TYPE_ITEM){
        holder.number.setText(row.getNumbering());
        holder.detail.setText(row.getDetail());
    }else
        holder.title.setText(row.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = null;
ViewHolder holder;

int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

ItemRow row = itemRow.get(position);

if(convertView == null){
    switch(rowType){
    case TYPE_ITEM:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_text, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textNumber);
        holder.detail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textItem);           

        view.setTag(holder);
        break;
    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_text, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textSection);            

        view.setTag(holder);
        break;
    }
} else{
    view = convertView;
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}

holder.number.setText(row.getNumbering());
        holder.detail.setText(row.getDetail());
holder.title.setText(row.getTitle());

return view;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately app has stopped. caused by NullPointerException